# Change FXML with multiple Controller already Instantiate into Container Panel

Tags: javafx, view, controller, instance

I have a class that has a container (FXML: vBox) where I want to press the button 1 or 2 to change the FXML panels already instantiated, it is similar to a TabbedPane, the drivers instantiate them at first, I do not want to be instanianciado each button Time I pulse because I can change SubPanel data and I do not want it to be erased.

```
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


    public class IngressMemberController {

    @FXML private VBox containerPanel;

    @FXML private Button sectionMemberBtn;
    @FXML private Button sectionMotherBtn;
    @FXML private Button saveBtn;

    MemberFormController memberController;
    MemberFormController motherController;

    public void initialize(int idPerson, int section){
    initContainerPanelMother(0, id_person, sectionCenter);
    initContainerPanelMother(1, id_person, sectionCenter);
    }

    private void initContainerPanelMember(int initTitle, int idPerson, int sectionCenter){
        FXMLLoader loader = transitionParameters(containerPanel, "clients/MemberForm");
        memberController = (MemberFormController)loader.getController();
        memberController.initialize(initTitle, idPerson, sectionCenter); 
    } 

    private void initContainerPanelMother(int initTitle, int idPerson, int sectionCenter){
        FXMLLoader loader = transitionParameters(containerPanel, "clients/MemberForm");
        memberController = (MemberFormController)loader.getController();
        memberController.initialize(initTitle, idPerson, sectionCenter); 
    }

    public FXMLLoader transitionParameters(VBox mainPanel, String destiny) {
        try {
            String path = "/view/" + destiny + ".fxml";
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
            mainPanel.getChildren().clear();
            mainPanel.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
            mainPanel.getChildren().add(loader.load());

                return loader;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return null;
        }

    private void  changeSubPanelAlreadyInstantiated(String destiny, MemberFormController controller){
           try {
                String path = "/view/" + destiny + ".fxml";
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));

                loader.setController(controller);

                containerPanel.getChildren().clear();
                containerPanel.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
                containerPanel.getChildren().add(loader.load());            

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IngressMemberController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }                
        }


    @FXML private void sectionMemberBtnAction(){
                        changeSubPanelAlreadyInstantiated("clientes/MemberForm", memberController);
               }

   @FXML private void sectionMotherBtnAction(){
             changeSubPanelAlreadyInstantiated("clientes/MemberForm", motherController);
           }
   @FXML private void saveBtnAction(){
            //Save changes 2 controllers in DataBase.
           }
        }
```